# Transposing the data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

My Data looks something like this

```
cust c1 p1 c2 p2 c3 p3
1    2  3  4  5  6  7
8    9  10 11 12 13 14
```

I want to transpose this data and return in below format:

```
cust c  p
1    2  3
1    4  5
1    6  7
8    9  10
8    11 12
8    13 14
```

Please Can someone suggest what to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function `lreshape` with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (pd.lreshape(df, {'c': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 'p': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']})
         .sort_values('cust'))

   cust   c   p
0     1   2   3
2     1   4   5
4     1   6   7
1     8   9  10
3     8  11  12
5     8  13  14
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne for the help! Also there is another function 'melt' which solves the problem.

Comment: Exactly - but it is a bit complicated - [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39853371/2901002).

Answer (score 1):

If you get the data in a list, you can use csv.

```
import csv

f = open('name.csv','wb')
csv = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')

csv.writerow([list[0]]+[list[1]]+...)
```

Answer (score 1):

if your data in a pandas data frame. you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df.transpose()# df is the name of data frame.
```

Or you can use directly:

```
df.T#In this case data frame name is df.T means transpose.
```

i think it will help you.